# Updating Arduino Wifi shield firmware update

Tags: arduino, wifi

I was trying to upgrade the wifi shield firmware as per the instructions provided on
http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/WiFiShieldFirmwareUpgrading

But I am getting the messege as

```
root@Joms-PC:/home/joms/arduino-1.0.5/hardware/arduino/firmwares/wifishield/scripts#      ./ArduinoWifiShield_upgrade.sh -f all

   Arduino WiFi Shield upgrade
 =========================================
 Instructions:
To access to the USB devices correctly, the dfu-programmer needs to have the root           permissions.

You can upgrade the firmware of the antenna togheter with the shield firmware or only    the shield firmware
if there aren't changes on the antenna firmware.
  Use the '-h' parameter for help
=========================================
```

How to provide root permission for dfu-programmer which I installed by

```
sudo apt-get install dfu-programmer
```

if that is the issue??? Or should I try something else

Comment: The instructions call for `sudo apt-get install dfu-programme` . There is no `r` at the end. Could this be the issue?

Comment: I think that is typo dfu-programme will not workout

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the script with sudo:

```
sudo ./ArduinoWifiShield_upgrade.sh -f all
```

also you will need to add the path to your Arduino IDE files with the -a switch (it has to be before the -f switch) so:

```
sudo ./ArduinoWifiShield_upgrade.sh -a PATH/TO/ARDUINO/FILES -f all
```

replace PATH/TO/ARDUINO/FILES with the path to where you have extracted the Arduino files.

Comment: Did this answer your question? if not, I can try to help if you give more info but if it did, can you please vote it up and mark it as a correct answer. Thanks.